# UIWebView and authentication challenge unable to authenticate

Tags: ios, security, uiwebview

http://m-qa-www.comixology.net/ this is the url when i am loading it on safari it works great.
but when i load it on uiwebview it does not do anything because of authentication challenge so i added support for authentication it works in for some url but it does not work for this above url.following is the code i am using for it.

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType;
{
    [self showNetworkIndicator];
    if (!authed && !conectionAlready) {
        authed = NO;
        conectionAlready=YES;
        urlCon=[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
        return YES;
    }
    return YES;
}

- (void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
    NSLog(@"webViewDidStartLoad");
    [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"window.alert=null;"];
    [self showNetworkIndicator];
    authed=NO;
}

-(void) webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
    //conectionAlready=NO;
    //[iWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"window.alert=null;"];
    NSString *currentURL = webView.request.URL.absoluteString;
    NSLog(@"current url %@",currentURL);
    URLBar.text=currentURL;
    if([iWebView canGoBack])
    {
        [backButton setEnabled:true];
    }
    else
    {
        [backButton setEnabled:false];
    }
    if([iWebView canGoForward])
    {
        [fwdButton setEnabled:true];
    }
    else
    {
        [fwdButton setEnabled:false];
    }
    [self hideNetworkIndicator];
}

-(void)webView:(UIWebView *)webView didFailLoadWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"url error ->%@",error.localizedDescription);
    [self hideNetworkIndicator];
    NSString *errorStr=error.localizedDescription;
    if ([errorStr rangeOfString:@"NSURLErrorDomain"].location==NSNotFound) {
        UIAlertView *alert=[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:nil message:@"A server with the specified hostname could not be found." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
        [alert show];
    }
}

-(void) showNetworkIndicator
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:YES];
}

-(void) hideNetworkIndicator
{
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge;
{
    authed = YES;
    authChallenge=challenge;
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Aithentication Required"
                                                    message:scRequest.URL.absoluteString
                                                   delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                                          otherButtonTitles:@"Log In", nil];
    [alert setAlertViewStyle:UIAlertViewStyleLoginAndPasswordInput];
    [alert show];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response;
{
    [connection cancel];
    conectionAlready=NO;
    NSHTTPURLResponse *httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse *)response;
    if ([response respondsToSelector: @ selector (allHeaderFields)]) {
        NSDictionary * dictionary = [httpResponse allHeaderFields];
        NSLog (@ "dictionary =%@", dictionary);
    }
    if (authed)
    {
        NSLog(@"remote url returned error %d %@",[httpResponse statusCode],[NSHTTPURLResponse localizedStringForStatusCode:[httpResponse statusCode]]);
        NSLog(@"The response is =%@",response);
        authed=YES;
        NSString *newUrl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", response.URL];
        NSLog(@"newURL%@",newUrl);
        scURL =[NSURL URLWithString:newUrl];
        scRequest=[NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:scURL];
        conectionAlready=NO;
        [iWebView loadRequest:scRequest];
    }
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    [self hideNetworkIndicator];
    authed=NO;
    conectionAlready=NO;
    NSLog(@"oops localizedDescription:%@",error.localizedDescription);
    NSLog(@"oops localizedFailureReason:%@",error.localizedFailureReason);
}

- (void) alertView:(UIAlertView *)alert clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    //NSLog(@"textFieldAtIndex0 %@",[alert textFieldAtIndex:0].text);
    //NSLog(@"textFieldAtIndex1 %@",[alert textFieldAtIndex:1].text);
    if (buttonIndex==0) {
        [[authChallenge sender] cancelAuthenticationChallenge:authChallenge];
    }
    else
    {
        [[authChallenge sender] useCredential:[NSURLCredential credentialWithUser:[[alert textFieldAtIndex:0] text] password:[[alert textFieldAtIndex:1] text] persistence:NSURLCredentialPersistenceNone] forAuthenticationChallenge:authChallenge];
    }
}

- (BOOL)connectionShouldUseCredentialStorage:(NSURLConnection *)connection;
{
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: UIWebView and authentication is PITA.

Comment: I am facing the same issue .any solution you found

Comment: Sorry i din't get any solution for that.

Answer (score 0):

Remember the webView is not so competent as a native browser. The native browser handles internally many exception which the webView is not at all competent of. I would suggest if you have the code for the link that you are hitting than try traversing the code and find errors for which the webView doesn't load. I encountered the same issue where some of my JS file were  non-responsive. There is no other way you can find bugs in a webView,as it provides limited set of delegated to actually traverse. :)

Comment: if i can open this in safari app then i am sure that there is everything ok with js

Comment: I know what you think. But webView is not so competent as of Safari. Try opening the same link using the native Chrome App downloaded from App Store.

Comment: Have you checked whether the webViewDilFailedLoading delegate is called or webViewDidFinishLoading ? May be you can get the hint of bug over there.

Comment: yes after validating didReceived is called then i am loading the request it goes to webViewDilFailedLoading method it does not call webViewDidFinishLoading

Comment: actually i tried it with safari safari shows me popup for http://m-qa-www.comixology.net/ url and when i enter the credential it shows me a popup again with other url qa-www.images.comixology.net and when i enter it loads the page on safari.

Comment: If the controls enter into didFailLoadWithError then check for the error that you are receiving. Print the error and let me know.

Comment: localizedDescription ->The operation couldn’t be completed. (NSURLErrorDomain error -999.)
localizedFailureReason ->(null)

Comment: m-qa-www.comixology.net need NSURLAuthenticationMethodDefault and qa-www.images.comixology.net needs NSURLAuthenticationMethodServerTrust challenge